# Handling Browser compatibilties with ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to capture keypress event for "ENTER" key for input box inside ADF editable table. I have added client listener and server listener and have the JavaScript code for the input box inside af:resource tag.

The requirement is as follows - 
   I have a editable table with total of 6 columns but only first and last columns are editable. So when user enters a value in first column and hits enter I need to populate some data from some other business component and fill the other columns.

I am able to capture the enter keypress event, but when I am using chrome after the server side method is called the row focus is automatically moved to next row in the table.
Can someone tell me how to stop this on the table. This happens only in chrome. The code works fine in firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You could set focus on the field you need through javascript on request. But you need to know the client Id of the component to set focus on.
Call this in your event handler:

```
String clientId = ...
String script = "AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('" + clientId + "').focus();";
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Service.getRenderKitService(context,
    ExtendedRenderKitService.class).addScript(context, script);
```

`script` will be called on the client when response is handled.